# Angular JS chaining two webservices calls

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Looking to get the right syntax to do the following :

```
1) empty object results = {}
2) first webservice call finished = results.webservice1 = data;
3) second webservice call finished = results.webservice2 = data;
4) Complete
```

I have something like this but syntax doesn't feel right

```
 function getClaimSummary(filter) {
        let deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(configSettings.Api.GetClaimSummary, filter, { withCredentials : true })
            .success(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function getPolicySummary(filter) {
        let deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(configSettings.Api.GetPolicySummary, filter, { withCredentials : true })
            .success(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function calculateAccumulations(filter){
        service.result = {};

        //Get Claims Summary
        getClaimSummary(filter).then(function(data){
            service.result.claims = data;
        }).then(getPolicySummary(filter).then(function(data){
            service.result.policy = data;
            showAccumulations();
        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` itself already returns a promise, so there's no need to create your own, you could also handle both promises at the same time instead of waiting for eachother like so:

```
function getClaimSummary(filter) {
    return $http.post(configSettings.Api.GetClaimSummary, filter, { withCredentials : true });
}

function getPolicySummary(filter) {
    return $http.post(configSettings.Api.GetPolicySummary, filter, { withCredentials : true });
}

function calculateAccumulations(filter){
    service.result = {};

    //Get Claims Summary
    $q.all({
        claims: getClaimSummary(filter),
        policy: getPolicySummary(filter)
    }).then(function (result) {
        service.result = result;
    });
}
```

You could even save some duplicate code doing it like so:

```
function fetchData(type, filter) {
    return $http.post(configSettings.Api[type], filter, { withCredentials : true });
}

function calculateAccumulations(filter){
    service.result = {};

    //Get Claims Summary
    $q.all({
        claims: fetchData('GetClaimSummary', filter),
        policy: getPolicySummary('GetPolicySummary', filter)
    }).then(function (result) {
        service.result = result;
    });
}
```

More information about `$q` can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Comment: Thanks thats perfect